# How to use a variable as execution time in crontab

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I want to use a var as one of the values in crontab. I'm using Ubuntu

```
#example 
rand=$(( ( RANDOM % 10 )  + 1 ))
rand * * * * /someScript.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not ever heard of such a possibility in `crontab`'s files. And I am not sure what you try to achieve. Is it possible to elaborate on that?

From `cron`'s manual,

> cron then wakes up every minute, examining all stored crontabs, checking  each  command to see if it should be run in the current minute.

However what you could do instead is have a script that is executed every minute and within that script you can generate a random number  and a threshold to decide whether to execute your `someScript.sh`

for example cron would look like

```
*/1 * * * * /gateScript.sh
```

and gateScript.sh would like :

```
#!/bin/bash
rand=${RANDOM}
threshold=16384 #middle value of possible $RANDOM outputs
if [ "${rand}" -gt "${threshold}" ]; then
    exec someScript.sh
fi
```

see [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/randomvar.html) for more elaborate "random" number generation.

Comment: I want to cloak web activity as human. I find a gateScript less readable, but guess Ill have to do it this way